# Linq multiple select by xml attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to select multiple "new" objects from xml file based on the attribute of the elements:
Example:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";
var names = new[] { "USD", "ROM", "SMT" };
var Cubes = from cube in XDocument.Load(@"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml").Root.Element(ns + "Cube").Elements(ns + "Cube")
                            where names.Contains(cube.Element(ns + "Cube").Attribute("currency").Value)
                            select new List<object>
                            {
                                new
                                {
                                datum = (DateTime)cube.Attribute("time"),
                                currency = (string)cube.Element(ns + "Cube").Attribute("currency"),
                                rate = (string)cube.Element(ns + "Cube").Attribute("rate")
                                }

                            };
```

The problem here is that I CAN select only the first  element by:
`cube.Element(ns+"Cube").Attribute("currency").Value`, so I want to be able to check all the cube's Elements:
`cube.Elements(ns+"Cube").Attributes("currency").Values` (plural) but its not possible like this. Any idea how to make more than one object? I have 3 strings in names so I need 3 different objects here. It works only for USD since its the first object.

My end result should be X lists each containing 3 objects.

Comment: Can you post sample XML?

Comment: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml
Its the link in XDocument.Load

Comment: What's `ns` in your code?

Comment: Its just the namespace, sorry I will add it now

Comment: @DENKOMANCHESKI - Hey but in your XML there is no tag with currency attribute as `ROM` or `SMT`.

Comment: @RahulSingh I just added it when i post it, it doesnt matter what i put there, it only selects the first element, if there isnt "USD" in the List of numbers it wont select anything, so if i choose other random currency attributes except USD, it wont select anything since it only checks the first one which is USD

Comment: Why are you using the variable name `datum` for a date field? "Datum" is a singular form of "data" and has nothing specific to do with dates. A single currency or rate figure could equally be called "datum".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml");
var names = new[] { "USD", "RON", "SMT" };
var someCubes =  xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "Cube")
    .Elements()
    .Select(x => x.Elements()
    .Where(y => names.Contains(y.Attribute("currency").Value)))
    .Select(x => {
        return x.Select(y => {
            return new {
                datum = (DateTime)y.Parent.Attribute("time"),
                currency = (string)y.Attribute("currency"),
                rate = (string)y.Attribute("rate")
            };
        });
    });
```

[image]

This is working just fine for me. Notice however that there are no elements in the XML that you linked that have either "ROM" or "SMT" as currencies. "RON" seems to be a valid one (so I have updated the names array accordingly) but I don't see "SMT".

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the anonymous object projection. Note that this returns an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> so you might want to .ToList() a couple places if it suits your needs.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot this is excatly what i needed. Is this an addon that makes the object projection look like this ? styled ?

Comment: I'm using a tool called LinqPad which allows you to execute arbitrary C# statements/expressions/programs without all the overhead of having to create a new project in visual studio. It adds the ability to "Dump" any variable so that you can see whats in it. Note in the screenshot that I wrote `someCubes.Dump()` which is what generates the bottom half

Comment: https://www.linqpad.net/  It's also how I knew that the other answers wouldn't suit your needs. Super simple to just drop their answers into LinqPad and call .Dump() to view the output. Its invaluable to my daily development and I highly recommend to all .NET programmers

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative using more of query syntax :

```
var Cubes = from cube in XDocument.Load(@"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml")
                                  .Root
                                  .Element(ns+"Cube")
                                  .Elements(ns+"Cube")
            select
            (
                from innercube in cube.Elements(ns+"Cube")
                where names.Contains((string)innercube.Attribute("currency"))
                select (object)new
                       {
                           datum = (DateTime)cube.Attribute("time"),
                           currency = (string)innercube.Attribute("currency"),
                           rate = (string)innercube.Attribute("rate")
                       }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. It creates many single item lists which separate the different currencies instead of 3 item lists that each of the currencies selected.

Comment: @JesseCarter thanks for correction, fixed it. Now it returns the correct `IEnumerable<List<object>>`

Comment: Nice answer, the query syntax can definitely be friendlier depending on the developer's background. +1